# Dev-C++ Application exits suddenly

Tags: c++, file, function

This is basically the code I have as of now:

```
void Menu1_Officer()
{
   customer cust;
   cust.enroll();
   cust.add_account();
};
```

When the cust.enroll() is called, this is what it looks like:

```
void customer::enroll()
{
       b.balance = 0;
       cout << "Please enter customer name: " << endl;
       cin >> c.Cust_Name;
       cout << "Please enter customer address: " << endl;
       cin >> c.address;
       cout << "Please enter username: (ONLY Numerals)" << endl;
       cin >> c.username;
       //blablabla these values are taken from the user
}
```

Once this is done with, the function is supposed to be sent back to the **void Menu1_Officer()** which then calls upon **cust.add_account();** for the next user input.

But in my case, as soon as the enroll() values are taken, the application quits itself back to the editor. Yes, I used **getch()**. In that case the application waits for an input to QUIT.

Suggestions folks?

Customer Class:

```
class customer
{
   public:
         char Cust_Name[50];
         char address[100];
         int username;
         int numOfAcc;
         bankAccount accs[10];
   public:

         void getAccountDetails();
         void displayAllCustomers();
         void detail_profile();
         void add_account();
         void enroll();
         int getuserName();
         void customerName();
};
```

Comment: Yes. Step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: What is c in the context of enroll?

Comment: customer c, object of customer class

Comment: Post the definition of `customer`, particularly the member types.

Comment: ok I added the customer class

Comment: Use debugger - it should help.
btw. As far as i know Dev-C++ is not supported for like 8 years now ;)

Comment: I know man, bloody college of mine still uses Dev-C++ for some reasons :)

Comment: Oh I see. Did you try to compile your code on any other compiler?

Comment: Other question - did you check if any instruction in add_account isn't actually processed?

Comment: You asked for suggestions: Do not use char arrays, use `std::string`, do not use hard coded numbers for things that differ per object (length of Cust_Name, size of accs. This should all be _dynamic_, e.g. with a std::vector.

Comment: @Yester it was resurrected some time ago: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/ This one carries an up to date compiler... for now. It has assumed a new name to torture all of us: Orwell.